# How to convert ppm to jpeg in java

Tags: java

Is there any way to convert ppm images to jpeg images in java?

Comment: check out this link http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai1_0_1guide-unc/Encode.doc.html

Comment: See also the [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) collection of plugins and extensions for Java's ImageIO.

Comment: A newer duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944954/convert-ppm-to-jpg-or-bmp-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php). It supports the [ppm](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) format, and has [Java APIs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php?ImageMagick=g41j6o1c3trili7s1h9ljnt8t1)